# Python exporter set armature to rest pose while exporting meshes

Tags: python, export, armature

I am exporting meshes attached to bones. For each mesh I have transform matrix
that is used to position mesh relative to bone. 
This relative matrix is calculated using:

```
obj.parent.data.bones[obj.parent_bone].matrix_local.inverted() * obj.matrix_local
```

When I export with armature in
rest position I get correct results.

[image: correct positions]

If I switch to pose position in blender and export, I get wrong results

[image: wrong positions]

I think that problem is `obj.matrix_local` which is based on current bone position.
How can I force rest position, or use other method to calculate object's transform
relative to bone.

`armature.data.pose_position = 'REST'` doesn't work from script, but looks like
it works from console.

Comment: I think that the problem is that an armature has 3 modes : Pose, Object and Edit. So What do you mean with putting it in rest mode? how can I proceed ? blender v2.78(a)

Answer (score 2):

I got `armature.data.pose_position` change to work
After changing to `REST` I had to call `context.scene.update()` and it calculates positions in rest pose. I change it once to pose when exporting keyframes and it is working as well.